# TypeError: descriptor 'append' for 'list' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object. Iterating through a folder and return a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

this is my first time trying to write a script on my own and I'm trying to make something that looks through my folders and return a list, and I'm keep getting this TypeError: descriptor 'append' for 'list' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object

anyone have any ideas? Thank you so much!

```
import os

path = input("Where you want to look?")

myFolder = list()
print("Here's your list of folders:")
for dirname in os.listdir(path):
    f = os.path.join(path,dirname)
    if os.path.isdir(f):
        for item in f:
            myFolder = list.append(f)

print(myFolder)
```

I've tried to change myFolder = list() to myFolder = list[] which resulted "none"

Comment: Have you tried `myFolder.append(f)`?

Comment: @AmriRasyidi, that wouldn't work either, because the `append()` method returns None.  You just want `myFolder.append(f)`.

Comment: `append` is an instance method, but you're accessing it from the type, not the list you want to append to.

Comment: in your second for loop, I'm guessing you want to get subdirectories in f folder. but you use the path string not the list of sub-directories of that path. use os.listdir(f) instead of f. and why you append to `list`, append to `myFolder that's your list`.

Comment: If you use `append` of `list` class, pass a list object as its first arguemnt, i.e., `list.append(myFolder, f)`. Or diectly use `append` of a list object, i.e., `myFolder.append(f)`. Both of them return `None`.

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing `append()` a bit - how should that method now to which list to append the values? You either have to specify the list `myFolder` as the first argument (`list.append(myFolder, f)`) or, a bit cleaner, call `append()` on the instance: `myFolder.append(f)`

You can read up a bit more on the [details in the docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). Take a look at the examples there.

So, altogether, your code should read like

```py
import os

path = input("Where you want to look?")

myFolder = list()
print("Here's your list of folders:")
for dirname in os.listdir(path):
    f = os.path.join(path,dirname)
    if os.path.isdir(f):
        for item in f:
            myFolder.append(f)

print(myFolder)
```

Answer (score 0):

I added three changes:

**myFolder = []**

**myFolder.append(f)** (Is not necessary to return and assign to variable)

*comment "for item in f " to get folder names without repeat more than once*

```
import os

path = input("Where you want to look?")
print("Here's your list of folders:")

myFolder = []
for dirname in os.listdir(path):
    f = os.path.join(path,dirname)
    if os.path.isdir(f):
        # for item in f: #comment this line to print only found folders
        myFolder.append(f)
print(myFolder)
```

Regards